# Add point to existing file with mouse click in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: point, arcgis-pro, editing

How do I add a point to a point shapefile in ArcGIS Pro 2.0?

All the modify options seemed geared toward polygons. I have looked through the documentation and can't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the Edit tab on the ribbon, click Create (see screenshot below), then select the layer you want to add points to in the Create Features pane. Afterwards, just make sure to save your Edits.

[image]